# IPython magic-command %notebook does not work when spaces are present in path (Google Colab)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory, ipython-magic

In jupyter-lab I can use the magic command `%notebook $output_file_path` to save the history notebook as a jupyter notebook. When I am working with Google Colab (mounting Google Drive) the path of my notebook folder is something like:

```
root_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/'
```

The problem is that, as I try to save the notebook history, the space between "My" and "Drive" makes the magic command fail

```
output_file_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/nb_history.ipynb'
%notebook $output_file_path
```

with the following error:

```
UsageError: unrecognized arguments: Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/nb_history.ipynb
```

---

I tried replacing the spaces with `"\"` or `"\\"` or `"\ "` or `"\\ "` with no success. I also tried to "embed"  the path string into quotes like

```
output_file_path = '"gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/nb_history.ipynb"'
```

with no success either, getting a different error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/nb_history.ipynb"'
```

---

Is there a workaround I can exploit to use the `%notebook` magic?

Comment: Save it in your current working directory without the path first and then move it using @55597 's answer? You say shell commands work, so `!mv` may work?

Comment: That would do the trick, but I would love to have a more "direct" solution

Comment: Same behavior. Maybe a limitation of Python 3.7's IPython?